# Dynamic added elements not removing on the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am adding the elements in html page on the select event, its working fine but when i click on remove icon corresponding to the element its not getting removed on single click. However it gets removed when i click twice.

```js
function addToFilter(divName) {
  console.log(divName);
  var val = document.getElementById('filter').value;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

  switch (val) {
    case 'mcus':
      newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='container'>Multi company use case &nbsp: " +
        "&nbsp;<select id='mcuc_selection'>" +
        "<option value='select'>--select--</option><option value='ags'>AGS</option><option value='agl'>AGL</option><option value='nafn'>NAFN</option></select>" +
        "&nbsp;&nbsp<img src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove' onclick='removeFilters();' onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;' class='remove-icon'>" +
        "<hr style='width:900px; margin-left:0px;'></div>";
      break;

    case 'oc':
      newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='container'>Order Condition &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:" +
        "&nbsp;&nbsp;<select id='oc_selection'><option value='select'>--select--</option><option value='1'>1</option>" +
        "<option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option>" +
        "<option value='6'>6</option><option value='7'>7</option>" +
        "</select> &nbsp;<img src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove' onclick='removeFilters();' onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;' class='remove-icon'>" +
        "<hr style='width:900px; margin-left:0px;'></div>";
      break;

    case 'ot':
      newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='container'>Order Type &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:" +
        "&nbsp;&nbsp;<select id='oc_selection'><option value='select'>--select--</option><option value='shadow'>shadow</option>" +
        "<option value='customer'>customer</option></select> &nbsp;" +
        "<img src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove' onclick='removeFilters();' onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;' class='remove-icon'>" +
        "<hr style='width:900px; margin-left:0px;'></div>";
      break;

    case 'dt':
      newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='container'>Date&Time&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:" +
        "<div id='startDate' class='input-append date' style='margin-left:165px; margin-top:-20px'>" +
        "<label>Start Date&Time: </label>" +
        "<input  id='date1' type='text' style='width:200px; height:15%'></input>" +
        "<span class='add-on' style='height:26px'>" +
        "<i id='dateIcon1' data-time-icon='icon-time' data-date-icon='icon-calendar'></i>" +
        "</span>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div id='endDate' class='input-append date' style='margin-left:550px; margin-top:-55px'>" +
        "<label>End Date&Time:&nbsp;</label>" +
        "<input type='text' style='width:200px; height:15%'></input>" +
        "<span class='add-on' style='height:26px'>" +
        "<i id='dateIcon1' data-time-icon='icon-time' data-date-icon='icon-calendar'></i>" +
        "</span>" +
        "</div>" +
        "&nbsp;<img src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove' onclick='removeFilters();' onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer; margin-left:780px; margin-top:-55px' class='remove-icon'><hr style='width:900px; margin-left:0px;'></div>";
      break;

  }
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  if (val == "dt") {
    callDate();
  }
}


function callDate() {
  $('#startDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss PP',
    language: 'en',
    pick12HourFormat: true
  });

  $('#endDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss PP',
    language: 'en',
    pick12HourFormat: true
  });
}


function removeFilters() {
  $(".remove-icon").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent(".container").remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="flt" class="x_content">
  <br>
  <div id="div_filter1">
    <div id="div_filter2">
      Add Filters&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:
      <select id="filter">
        <option value="select">--select--</option>
        <option value="mcus">Multi Company Use Case</option>
        <option value="oc">Order Condition</option>
        <option value="ot">Order Type</option>
        <option value="dt">Date&Time</option>
        <option value="oi">Order Id</option>
        <option value="si">Shipment Id</option>
        <option value="pi">Purchase Id</option>
      </select>
      &nbsp;
      <img id="add-icon" src="add-icon.jpg" alt="add" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="addToFilter('div_filter1');">
      <button id="go" type="submit" value="Submit">Go</button>
      <br>
      <hr style='width:1100px; margin-left:0px; margin-top: 20px;'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is because on the first click you call `removeFilters()` which adds the jQuery click handler which does the work. Then on the second click you add another click handler, but the previous one does the work you expect. Instead you should look at using delegated event handlers.

Comment: You should also look in to using templates for generating that much HTML, and also using classes for your styling over inline attributes.

Comment: How to do this with delegated event handlers can you help more a bit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements?rq=1